# How do I set a boolean for a specified amount of time, then reset it?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I basically want a method I can call that will set a boolean to true for 2 seconds, then reset it to false. How would I do this?

I'm using the Slick library which is dependent on LWJGL.

Comment: This was very helpful: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at the [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

check out the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and the method [schedule()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)